# Acess file from isolated storage using its full path as URI

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

I want to use the file in isolated storage using its full path(like URI), I know there is sandboxed api to access isolated storage. But i have to load the images using their paths.

So is it possible ?

Comment: Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx).

Comment: @Romasz it is not isolated storage related.

Comment: You want to get the source path of the image which is stored in isolated storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it like this:

```
 public string GetAbsolutePathOfFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var isfs = storage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                    FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                return isfs.Name; // this return the absolute path.
            }
        }
    }
```